# Right clicking in WinAPI context menu

Tags: c, winapi, contextmenu

I create a context menu like this:

**Resource file:**

```
IDR_CONTEXT MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP ""
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "Add &last",   ID_ADDLAST
        MENUITEM "Add &before", ID_ADDBEFORE
        MENUITEM "Add &after",  ID_ADDAFTER
        MENUITEM "&Remove",     ID_REMOVE
    END
END
```

And the **window procedure**:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message) {
        case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
            {
                POINT cursor;
                GetCursorPos(&cursor);
                TrackPopupMenu((HMENU) GetSubMenu(LoadMenu(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_CONTEXT)), 0), TPM_LEFTALIGN, cursor.x, cursor.y, 0, hWnd, NULL);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't allow me to right click on the items in the context menu. I can only left click on them...
How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [the documentation page for `TrackPopupMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648002.aspx), you will find a flag described as "The user can select menu items with both the left and right mouse buttons."

Comment: Thanks! Why did I forget to look at the documentation anyway?

Comment: @Midas: Because SO is often more convenient?  But it's polite to only ask for help with things the documentation leave unclear.